# In Laravel 4, how might I kill a response, so that my API will simply not respond?

Tags: php, api, laravel, laravel-4

I have tried to extend the Response object with a kill() method, and arrest a response, but as soon as the response processes, Laravel returns a session_cookie.

How to 'create' a NULL response sans http status code, header, body, etc.?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but have you tried just doing `exit` without returning anything?

Comment: good thought. it returns a 200.

Comment: might I from PHP redirect/forward to a null endpoint, or something caught at the htaccess level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use PHP as a module in Apache, Apache will always return a response, even if PHP has crashed (you'll get a 500 Internal Server Error).
In certain cases, Apache could return nothing, but it's only because Apache has crashed.

All you can do is to flush the PHP output cache with `ob_clean` and `die()` in your `kill()` function. You could return a HTTP 500 error, too.

Comment: Not exactly what I was hoping for, but it prevents me from searching further. I'll return a 500.